# Combining two input events

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am aiming to remove the javascript from the input so i’m writing a bit of jquery

the javascript:

```
    <input type="text" id = "IDthisinput'" class="CLthisinput'"  placeholder="First"
            onChange   = "dosomething();"
            onKeyPress = "this.onchange();"
            onpaste    = "this.onchange();"
            oninput    = "this.onchange();"
    />
    <span id="ReturnedMsg"></span>
    <span id="IDActionVal"></span>
```

the jquery:

```
    $('.CLthisinput').on('keyup', function () {
            $('#ReturnedMsg').html(dotuff('#'+this.id,$(this).val()));
            $('#IDActionVal').html('#'+this.id + '  ' + 'keyup ' + $(this).val());
    });
    $('.CLthisinput').on('paste', function () {
            $('#ReturnedMsg').html(dotuff('#'+this.id,$(this).val()));
            $('#IDActionVal').html('#'+this.id + '  ' + 'keyup ' + $(this).val());
    });
```

I’m stumped when it comes to shortening the above, which works fine, to something like this:

```
    $('.CLthisinput').on('keyup', 'paste', function () {
            var theaction = event
            $('#ReturnedMsg').html(dotuff('#'+this.id,$(this).val()));
            $('#IDActionVal').html('#'+this.id + '  ' + theaction + '  ' + $(this).val());
    });
```

How can I get the events to work together?!

Comment: where you see the class name thisinput (in Lumino's and Dzmitry's answers below) it should read CLthisinput. the discrepancy originates from my typo in my original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate both events in the same string, separated by space:

```
$('.thisinput').on('keyup paste', function () {
        var theaction = event
        $('#ReturnedMsg').html(dotuff('#'+this.id,$(this).val()));
        $('#IDActionVal').html('#'+this.id + '  ' + theaction + '  ' + $(this).val());
});
```

You can’t pass them as separate arguments, because `$('.thisinput').on('keyup', 'paste', ...)` does something completely different: it fires when a `keyup` event occurs inside `<paste>` tag inside `.thisinput` (and allows `<paste>` tags to be added dynamically).

You can use `event.type` to find out the type of the event:

```
$('.thisinput').on('keyup paste', function () {
        var theaction = event
        $('#ReturnedMsg').html(dotuff('#'+this.id,$(this).val()));
        $('#IDActionVal').html('#'+this.id + '  ' + theaction.type + '  ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Also, don’t use the global `event` object (also known as `window.event`). This is a [non-standard extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) introduced by Microsoft, it will not work in Firefox. Instead, pass the event as an argument to your callback:

```
$('.thisinput').on('keyup paste', function (event) {
        var theaction = event
        $('#ReturnedMsg').html(dotuff('#'+this.id,$(this).val()));
        $('#IDActionVal').html('#'+this.id + '  ' + theaction.type + '  ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Also, you don’t really need `theaction` and `event` to be separate variables:

```
$('.thisinput').on('keyup paste', function (theaction) {
        $('#ReturnedMsg').html(dotuff('#'+this.id,$(this).val()));
        $('#IDActionVal').html('#'+this.id + '  ' + theaction.type + '  ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: thanks I now see it, I added a var theaction so I can identify which event it was, any help there

Comment: i like it, I like the solution and the explanation too. Thanks.

Comment: i like Lumio's answer too, which I'm sure those two events would have been enumerated in the same string had I not made a typo in the CLass name. Cheers for both routes.

Comment: re: .type cheers,  it's the teach yourself route that's holding me back! i must have read that one @ https://api.jquery.com/event.type/ a dozen times in the past, your putting my var as the function param has connected a few more neurons!!

Answer (score 2):

Another way would also be to outsource that function, like so:

```
var helper = function() {
  $('#ReturnedMsg').html(dotuff('#'+this.id,$(this).val()));
  $('#IDActionVal').html('#'+this.id + '  ' + 'keyup ' + $(this).val());
}
$('.CLthisinput').on('keyup', helper);
$('.thisinput').on('paste', helper);
```

Comment: i like this and Dzmitry's answer. Going to accept that answer because of the added explanation. But great to see two working alternatives. Thanks.